# check all inedx of array object one by one in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

how to check all array of object index one by one if first index quantity value greater then 0 then stop otherwise goes to next index

```
[{id:1,item:'Refresh Listing',quantity:3,priceEach:90,},
   {id:2,item:'Premium Listing',quantity:2,priceEach:1000},
   {id:3,item:'Hot Listing',quantity:5,priceEach:1500},
   {id:4,item:'Super Hot Listing',quantity:2,priceEach:8000}]
```

Comment: That is exactly what [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find` like so:

```js
const data = [{id:1,item:'Refresh Listing',quantity:3,priceEach:90,},{id:2,item:'Premium Listing',quantity:2,priceEach:1000},{id:3,item:'Hot Listing',quantity:5,priceEach:1500},{id:4,item:'Super Hot Listing',quantity:2,priceEach:8000}];
const res = data.find(({ quantity }) => quantity > 0);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: No problem @SohailAhmed, always glad to help.